# Million row csv files, need row count

Tags: unix, count, row

I have 90 csv files in a folder, each file quite large, how can I get the row count of all csv files in one text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to use a python script and can do this on a *NIX commandline:

```
wc -l *.csv > outputfilename
```

If you really want to do this with python:

```
import os
import csv

dirname = 'directory/with/csv/files'
outfile = open('path/to/output/file')
for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
    if not fname.endswith('.csv'):
        continue
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, fname)) as infile:
        numlines = sum(1 for row in csv.reader(infile))
        outfile.write("file {} contains {} lines\n".format(fname, numlines))
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This method of *counting rows* is about 5x faster than `sum(generator-expression)` with a one-million row file.  It just counts all the newline characters.

```
with open(csv_file) as f:
    s = f.read()
numlines =  s.count('\n')
```

You might want to substitute into @inspectorG4dget's solution and see if it makes a difference.